# how can I multiply two fields then get avg of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to make avg of grades

there is a table like this (INNER JOIN of two table)

```
+-------+------+
| grade | unit |
+-------+------+
```

I want to get multiply of (grade & unit) as res

then, get avg of res

I can do it by php, but i need to make it only with one sql and the result must be in

one field

thank alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(grade * unit) FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select grade,unit, AVG(grade *unit) as average from ...
```